# regex combination of two lookaround - regexstorm.net

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have to collect two informantion from a text using regex. The name and the database and relate then in one table. But a can only collect then individually.

This is an example, i have many blocks of these, and two of then don't have a database value, these i need to ingnore

```
[SCD] {I need the name between []}
Driver=/opt/pcenter/pc961/ODBC7.1/lib/DWmsss27.so
Description=
Database=scd {I need the value after Defaut|Database}
Address=#######
LogonID=######
Password=######
QuoteId=No
AnsiNPW=No
ApplicationsUsingThreads=1
```

The regex to find the name is:

```
(?<=\[)(.*)(?=\])
```

The regex to find the value after database is

```
(?<=Defaut|Database=)(.*)
```

How can i combine both of then into onde regex ?

Comment: Try `Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<=\[)[^][]*(?=])|(?<=(?:Defaut|Database)=).*").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

To match both values you could use 2 capturing groups instead and use a repeating pattern and a negative lookahead to check if a line do not start with Default of Database until the line does.

```
\[([^]]+)\](?:\r?\n(?!Default|Database).*)*\r?\n(?:Default|Database)=(\S+)
```

About the pattern

- `\[` Match `[`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^]]+` match 1+ times not `]`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\]` Match `]`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n` Match newline,
  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not

    - `Default|Database` Match one of the options
  - `).*` Close negative lookahead and match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `\r?\n(?:Default|Database)=` Match newline, any of the options and `=`
- `(\S+)` Capturing group 2, match 1+ times a non whitespace char (or use `(.+)` to match any char 1+ times)

[regexstorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%28%5b%5e%5d%5d%2b%29%5c%5d%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!Default%7cDatabase%29.*%29*%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f%3aDefault%7cDatabase%29%3d%28%5cS%2b%29&i=%5bSCD%5d%0d%0aDriver%3d%2fopt%2fpcenter%2fpc961%2fODBC7.1%2flib%2fDWmsss27.so%0d%0aDescription%3d%0d%0aDatabase%3dscd%0d%0aAddress%3d%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%0d%0aLogonID%3d%23%23%23%23%23%23%0d%0aPassword%3d%23%23%23%23%23%23%0d%0aQuoteId%3dNo%0d%0aAnsiNPW%3dNo%0d%0aApplicationsUsingThreads%3d1&o=m)

[image]